# 「オントピック」と「オフトピック」を統一するタグの作成を提案します

Tags: 討議, タグ, 話題の範囲

メタサイトにタグを新設し、[オントピック](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%aa%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%83%94%e3%83%83%e3%82%af) と [オフトピック](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%aa%e3%83%95%e3%83%88%e3%83%94%e3%83%83%e3%82%af) をこの新設タグの別名（タグシノニム）として設定することを提案します。

理由は以下です。

- 「（オン/オフ）トピック」ではサイト初心者に伝わりにくい
- [オントピック](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%aa%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%83%94%e3%83%83%e3%82%af) と [オフトピック](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%aa%e3%83%95%e3%83%88%e3%83%94%e3%83%83%e3%82%af) を使い分ける場面は無いと思われ、このままだと必ず両方指定することになり冗長である
- 本家では既に [scope](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/scope/synonyms) に統一されており、これに倣うのがシンプル

---

この提案への賛否に加え、新設するとしたらその新設タグ名を何にするか、回答にてご意見いただければと思います。

Comment: 「話題の範囲」で統一いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[話題の範囲](/questions/tagged/%e8%a9%b1%e9%a1%8c%e3%81%ae%e7%af%84%e5%9b%b2) に[統一](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%e8%a9%b1%e9%a1%8c%e3%81%ae%e7%af%84%e5%9b%b2/synonyms)していただきました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

統一には賛成です。タグ名の候補としては「(質問|討議|話題)の範囲」辺りでしょうか。

Comment: 話題の範囲、が一番実態に近い表現だな、と思っています。

Comment: 問題がなければ、ひとまず「話題の範囲」で統一しようと思っています。

Comment: 「話題の範囲」で統一いたしました。

Answer (score 0):

タグを統一することに +1

ただ、個人的には「質問の範囲」よりは「サイトのスコープ」の方がいいかな、と思っています。

Comment: タグ名の議論がしやすいように質問を変更しました。確かに「質問の範囲」は文脈によっては別の意味合いになりますし、もう少し考えてみます。

Comment: 「サイトのスコープ」だと「(オン/オフ)トピック」以上に伝わりにくい気がします。

Comment: @cubick なんと。。スコープ、で通ずる英語圏がうらやましくなりますね…

Comment: @YukiInoue プログラムの話をしている内は「スコープ」でもいいのかもしれませんが、ここではもっと一般的な話になると思うので。考えはじめてみると中々難しいですね。

Comment: スコープの意味自体は通じるのですがMETAとは言え「プログラム上のスコープの話？」と混乱しそうです。また、WEBプログラマの方の中にはスコープ自体の意味を掴めない方もいそうです。